# Calculate historical SF from unit history table (with dplyr)

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have a table/tibble named dat with history of square footages for suites in an office building. These SF's change over time.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

```
dat

# A tibble: 12 x 4
   BLDGID SUITID EFFDATE      SQFT
   <chr>  <chr>  <date>      <dbl>
 1 2828   100    2018-09-01    547
 2 2828   100    2011-05-31    547
 3 2828   100    2010-01-02    549
 4 2828   100    2010-01-01    549
 5 2828   100    2009-11-01  91686
 6 2828   100    2007-01-01 114607
 7 2828   100    2000-01-01 137484
```

Here is a subset of my data for the reproducible example (only 1 building and 2 units):

```
dat <-
structure(list(BLDGID = c("2828", "2828", "2828", "2828", "2828", 
"2828", "2828", "2828", "2828", "2828", "2828", "2828"), SUITID = c("100", 
"100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "1000", "1000", "1000", 
"1000", "1000"), EFFDATE = structure(c(17775, 15125, 14611, 14610, 
14549, 13514, 10957, 14914, 14611, 14610, 12965, 11231), class = "Date"), 
    SQFT = c(547, 547, 549, 549, 91686, 114607, 137484, 12000, 
    22921, 22921, 547, 756)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

There are not begin and end dates, but the information is there in the EFFDATE column. This field basically means the date the new SF took affect. So for Unit 100 the SF was 91,686 from 2009-11-01 through 2009-12-31. Then the SF changed to 549 SF (beginning on 2010-01-01).

I would like to take this information and generate a tibble that shows the actual amount over time.

The desired output would look something like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  BLDGID SUITID dates      actual_sf
  <chr>  <chr>  <date>         <dbl>
1 2828   100    2009-11-01     91686
2 2828   100    2009-12-01     91686
3 2828   100    2010-01-01       549
4 2828   100    2010-02-01       549
```

I'm thinking I need to create a tibble with dates.

```
my_dates <- tibble(dates = ymd('2009-11-01') + months(0:4))

my_dates
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  dates     
  <date>    
1 2009-11-01
2 2009-12-01
3 2010-01-01
4 2010-02-01
5 2010-03-01
```

And the join dat to my_dates in some what, but I can't figure out how this might work.

Comment: The dates part is not clear

Comment: Thank you akrun. I edited the question. Hope it is clearer.

Comment: How are you getting the `949` value

Comment: The output tibble is just how I want the layout to be. I just made up numbers for the value in the actual_sf column.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show the exact numbers because people will be crosschecking your expected output

Comment: May be you need a non-equi join (`setDT(my_dates)[setDT(dat), .(dates, actual_sf = sum(SQFT)), on = .(dates > EFFDATE), by = .EACHI]`

Comment: Thank you akrun. I made edits to my question. Hopefully it is clearer. It looks like that syntax is from DT, is a non-equi join possible in dplyr?

Comment: You can uses `fuzzy_join` where it can do the comparison operator in `match_fun`

Comment: i.e. `fuzzy_inner_join(my_dates, dat, by = c('dates' = 'EFFDATE'), match_fun = list(`>=`))`  The `>=` is within backquotes